# View deletes messages on facebook

Tags: facebook

I've deleted all my messages from a contact and now I realize that I need some information from there. **So I would like to know if there is a way for viewing deleted messages**.

I have searched the answer on many sites and forums, but the only solution I found was something with archived messages and unfortunately I don't have an archive with those messages. So, if you know another way, please tell me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't not have an archive for messages on Facebook.  Go in to your message center (click the messages icon on the top right of Facebook and select "See all").  On the top left there is a "More" button.  Click that and select "Archived" to view all of your deleted messages.

Comment: I have found those things, but when I select Archived, there isn't any message.

Answer (score 0):

Each message deleted is totaly removed from your account (not from Facebook server). You can't have access to them.